# tmux doesn't want to be installed

Tags: linux, software-installation, apt, packages

I had my Raspberry Pi running for a while and needed to uninstall all the junk I left behind for a project.

I used tmux before and it was a blessing.
I am trying to install it again, but it doesn't work.

Since it's in german I'll try to translate the error messages for you:
Original:

```
$ sudo apt-get install tmux
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
Probieren Sie »apt-get -f install«, um dies zu korrigieren:
Die folgenden Pakete haben unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten:
libavresample-dev : Hängt ab von: libavutil-dev (= 6:11.9-1~deb8u1+rpi1) soll aber nicht installiert werden
E: Unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten. Versuchen Sie »apt-get -f install« ohne Angabe eines Pakets (oder geben Sie eine Lösung an).
```

Translated:

```
$ sudo apt-get install tmux
Reading package lists... Ready
Creating dependency tree.
Reading status informations... Ready
Try »apt-get -f install« to correct following:
The following packages have unfulfilled dependencies:
libavresample-dev : Depends on: libavutil-dev (= 6:11.9-1~deb8u1+rpi1) but shouldn't be installed
E: Unfulfilled dependencies. Try »apt-get -f install« without adding a package (or write a solution)
```

What do I have to do here? Installing the dependencies seems not to work aswell, Install Guides from the internet are not working, `sudo apt-get -f install` isn't working, ...

I don't know what to do :/

Comment: Have you tried installing from source. An additional benefit is that you will get an updated version compared to what is in the package repo.

Comment: well, I am not the best with unix - I don't know by myself what to do. I probably did try to install it from source: this is the link I used https://gist.github.com/VladSem/e706a7755873cccefa8d. The original tmux-2.0.tar.gz doesn't exist anymore it seems and at the bottom of the page is another link which downloads correctly, but the `./configure` doesn't exist or work. Can you maybe explain what I have to enter or how I have to look up the correct source?

Comment: Try the instructions here https://github.com/tmux/tmux you will need git installed or try this post from our blog https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/141348857424/tmux-101-installing-from-source you can replace 2.1 with 2.4

Comment: well, thank you for that. Problem is, that if I try to execute `./configure` it tells me `configure: error: "curses not found"` after a while and the `make` command cant be executed because it can't find the control file `make: *** No targets given and no »make« control file found. End.` ....installing from git the `autogen.sh` won't execute with the error `autogen.sh: 15: autogen.sh: aclocal: not cound aclocal failed`

Comment: Try this to install ncurses sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev

Comment: that gives me a similar dependency error like the one at the top with `libavresample-dev : Depends on: libavutil-dev`, `libncurses5-dev : depends on: libtinfo-dev` and `libncursesw5-dev : Depends on: libtinfo-dev` :/

Comment: you have to install the dependencies then rerun the ncurses install

Comment: that isn't working either - `dpkg-deb: Error: child process got killed by signal ( file transfer interrupted (broken pipe))` `E: Sub-process /use/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)` ... googled that, tried to update everything again and not even `sudo apt-get upgrade` is working now. it tells me that `libavresample-dev : depends on libavutil-dev` ??

Comment: You appear to have screwed up your system while trying to remove stuff. I suggest you backup the important files and burn a new SD card and start fresh.

Comment: mh ok, thanks - I didn't even remove stuff. I just realized that I couldn't move files I was able to move minutes ago and that I couldn't install some programs via apt-get ...

Comment: What version of raspbian are you using?

Comment: What is the output of `cat /etc/os-release`?

Comment: whooops, sorry: `Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)`

Answer (score 4):

This can actually happen over time with innocent runs of `sudo apt update` or installing various packages that conflict rather indirectly. When it tells you there's a dependency like `libavutil-dev` that "is not going to be installed", try to install it alongside, i.e.:

```
sudo apt install libavutil-dev tmux
```

If it then gives a message about a third dependency that is "not going to be installed", you can extend the command further with even more required packages.

What often eventually happens it that it'll turn out that installing the set will require removing something else, indicated clearly by the message "The following packages will be REMOVED". As long as you don't run with the `-y` flag you need not worry about doing damage until you decide to select yes or no depending on whether the resulting packages are expendable.

As Steve suggested it is possible to be in a state such that your packages are truly broken, but the majority of the time the "not going to be installed" error is conveniently resolvable and certainly worth investigating.

As for building from source, that could still work too. Per your error messages and the tmux README you need to install at a minimum:

```
sudo apt install libncurses5-dev libevent-dev autoconf automake pkg-config
```

and possibly other requirements before running `./autogen.sh` and `configure`. One downside is that you might end up in the same package conflict situation depending on what's required! At the very least it'll give you more insight into the true dependency conflicts at hand.